# Why do I need to parse dates in Grails?

Tags: date, grails, parameters, formatting, action

I am in the unfortunate position that I need to use a composite id in a Grails app where I work with legacy data. This means I have to override some actions in the controller, but as I did this I was struck by the fact that I could not use use a date argument directly as a parameter to a dynamic method.

Instead of just doing `MyLegacyObj.findBySystemIdAndLogDate(params.systemId, params.logDate)`, I first needed to parse the date string before giving it to the dynamic method. To further complicate matters I had no idea what format the date string had (until I added lots of log.debug() string to the output). So now I have a bit of code looking like this

```
def formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss z yyyy")
MyLegacyObj.findBySystemIdAndLogDate(params.systemId, formatter.parse(params.logDate));
```

This feels unoptimal, no to say dangerous (what if the date format changes with the locale?)? What would be a recommended way of doing this, and do I really need to parse dates at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Date` is a pretty complex object and `params` are just `String`s, so `Date` is submitted in parts. It is "magically" assembled from the parts when assigning `x.properties = params`.

[Command object](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/6.%20The%20Web%20Layer.html#6.1.10%20Command%20Objects) will do the work for you, if you add a `Date` field to it.

It has nothing to do with methods' dynamic or static invocation. Your GSP that renders `Date` editor might interfere too.